# Express.static() en Cpanel no sirve CSS

Tags: css, nodejs, cpanel

¿Cómo se puede usar express.static() en Cpanel? En localhost funciona todo bien, pero una vez lo subo al server me da este mensaje:

*`Refused to apply style from 'https://page/cms/login.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`*

Ya he intentado de 1000 formas distintas y nada.

La App Node está alojada en la url `cms`. Cabe aclarar que también uso rutas y todo funciona bien menos eso.

Incluso hice esto para ver de qué modo servía y ninguno funcionó:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/global.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./global.css" />
```

Actualmente así está configurado express.static():

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Y ya use esta:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como servir correctamente archivos estáticos en node.js?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310831/como-servir-correctamente-archivos-est%c3%a1ticos-en-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al fin lo pude solucionar. Espero poder ayudar a alguien que esté pasando por lo mismo:

En Cpanel la ruta donde está alojada la app Node es en `/cms`

Esta es la estructura de mi app:

```
cms
  |-frameworks
       |- webserver
              |-server.js
  |-public
       |global.css
```

Lo que hice fue establecerlo a esta forma:

```
app.use('/cms/public',  express.static(process.cwd()  + '/public'))
```

Y las rutas del htlm:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cms/public/global.css">
```

Y listo, todo funcionó de maravilla.

Me imagino que debe ser por la forma en como Cpanel asigna las rutas de las app Node.