# Creo un express public y no me deja utilizar mi archivo javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

He creado un archivo index.js para crear una sección de la página web mediante un servidor express public y ahora quiero modificar mi archivo main.js para hacer un menu desplegable y no me deja. Me sale el siguiente error que os adjunto en la pantalla. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
He intentado poner lo que quiero modificar del html mediante javascript en el archivo index.js creado para coger los datos de los clientes y tampoco funciona.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Intento probar a proner lo que quiero modificar en el archivo de javascript y tampoco me deja.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no hago un peticion de datos con node y express y hago solo el html,css y javascript si funciona pero cuando hago la peticion de datos y quiero cambiar algo de la página html con javascript no se porque no me deja.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, el código y todos los datos relevantes **han de colocarse como texto**. Las imágenes pueden desaparecer en cualquier momento: ¿ Que pasa si el sitio que las contiene se *cae* ? Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como servir correctamente archivos estáticos en node.js?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310831/como-servir-correctamente-archivos-est%c3%a1ticos-en-node-js)