# Servir un fichero externo a un documento HTML

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estoy utilizando NodeJs para hacer pruebas, y necesito poder enlazar dos cosas:

1. Un archivo javascript
2. Un faivon

Ahora mismo, tengo un Js llamado `app.js` desde el que inicializo el servidor, a la escucha en el puerto 5000, y que responde con el html correspondiente:

```
let sql = require('mysql');
let app = require('express')();
let http= require('http').Server(app);

let con = sql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'test_database'
    });

/***************/
function startServer(query){
    http.listen(5000, function() {
        console.log('listening on port 5000')
    });

    app.get('/',function(req,res,query){
        res.sendfile("./025.html");
    });

    app.get('/',function(req,res){
        res.sendfile("./img/favicon.jpg");
    });
}
```

(Aclaración: el uso de sendfile con la ruta relativa, y sendFile con la ruta completa, me da el mismo resultado)

El HTML está vacío, lo único que tiene el `link` al `JS` correspondiente:

```
<script src="js/025.js"></script>
```

El Js en cuestión solamente tiene un `console.log('hola')`, para saber que funciona correctamente.

Pero siempre me salta el mismo error:

```
GET localhost:5000/js/025.js 404
```

¿Qué tengo que hacer para poder ver el archivo?

También he probado a poner un get en el app.js:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile("./js/025.js");
});
```

Pd: Este es el árbol:

```
.
├── 025.html
├── app.js
├── css
├── js
│   └── 025.js
├── img
│   └── favicon.jpg
├── json
├── node_modules (aqui hay mucha mierda)
│
├── package.json
└── package-lock.json
```

Comment: Mira esta pregunta tal vez te ayude https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310831/como-servir-correctamente-archivos-est%C3%A1ticos-en-node-js

Comment: Muchas gracias! No la había visto