# Error - Uncaught SyntaxError: private fields are not currently supported - como solucionarlo

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ejs

Estoy intentando ejecutar código javascript en una plantilla **EJS** en un proyecto de **NODE JS**.
He creado un archivo **.js** en la carpeta **'public/javascripts'** y lo en enlazado correctamente en el archivo **EJS**.
La cuestión es que cuando defino una función o declaro una variable **no las localiza** y me aparece el error **'Uncaught SyntaxError: private fields are not currently supported'** o **'nombreFuncion' is not defined**.
Alguien sabe el por que?
Se accede a los archivos mediante **'public'** porque he puesto:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Aún así no detecta ni las funciones ni las variables, alguien sabe el por que?
Para probar que el archivo esta bien enlazado ejecuto la función **'alert("hola")'** y me muestra el resultado por pantalla correctamente por el contrario cuando defino las funciones o las variables y ejecuto la pagina web no funcionan. No funciona ni con **onclick='nombreFuncion()'**, ni con **onload='nombreFuncion()'** ni con nada.
Si alguien me puede explicarme el por que se lo agradecería.
Gracias de ante mano !

Comment: Falta más información para poder ayudarte en tu problema. ¿Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de tu archivo de script? ¿Puedes mostrar cómo lo estás enlazando en tu plantilla `ejs`? Saludos

Comment: El archivo está bien enlazado porque si ejecuto simplemente un alert('texto') me lo ejecuta sin problemas, lo malo que cuando declaro una variable o una función ya me salta el error y no me permite ejecutar el javascript.
He probado a ejecutar directamente document.getElemetById('id').style.background = #000; y no me lo ejecuta. Tampoco me devuelve más información del error ni nada, únicamente 'Uncaught SyntaxError: private fields are not currently supported' o 'function is not defined'.
Como podría extraer más información del error? Alguna idea?

Comment: Para el error de `private field` debes consultar la [compatibilidad](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_classes_private_class_fields) del navegador que utilizas, no es una característica estándar. Pero aún así, es una suposición, ya que sin ver el código de tu script, es poco lo que puedo aportar.

Comment: Es que el script lo tengo sin crear todavía porque como me da error directamente al crear una variable o una función pues lo tengo sin hacer.
Como tendrían que ser los pasos a seguir para poder ejectuar javascript normal en el Front-end con node js?
Yo lo que he hecho es poner esta linea de código para que coja como ruta de javascript la carpeta 'public'
```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```
Por lo demás es poner en la ruta la carpeta 'Javascripts' y nombre del archivo no? O tengo que hacer algo más?

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310831/como-servir-correctamente-archivos-est%c3%a1ticos-en-node-js/311082#311082) sobre el uso de Express para servir archivos estáticos. Saludos