# ¿como puedo añadir el css en el modulo servidor http?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Este es mi codigo de javaScript, estoy utilizando el modulo http, como puedo anadir mi archivo css la tengo en la ruta assets\css\index.css

```js
const http = require("http");
//const path = require("path");
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const host = 'localhost';
const port = 8000;

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/index.html" )
        .then(contents => {
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end(contents);
        })
};



const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`'app funcionando en el puerto 8000 http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

al momento de ejcutarlo solo tengo el html, sin nada de estilos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como servir correctamente archivos estáticos en node.js?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310831/como-servir-correctamente-archivos-est%c3%a1ticos-en-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo de la forma que estás haciendolo, debes identificar el tipo de archivo solicitado y trabajar sobre los headers, el css lo invocas desde el html de la siguiente manera ej:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

Entonces cuando se llame a "/", lo primero agregará el content-type: text/html, cuando el html intenta llamar al archivo css, detecta que la url hace un match con .css y agrega el header correspondiente y así consecutivamente, en el ejemplo también está hecho para que funcionen archivos .js, y está programado para que tanto los js como los css estén dentro de una carpeta de nombre "public" que debe estar en el mismo lugar que el index.html.

**Código server.js**

```
const http = require("http");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const host = "localhost";
const port = 8000;

const HTML_CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html";
const CSS_CONTENT_TYPE = "text/css";
const JS_CONTENT_TYPE = "text/javascript";

const PUBLIC_FOLDER = path.join(__dirname, "public");

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
  const { url } = req;
  let statusCode = 200;
  let contentType = HTML_CONTENT_TYPE;
  let stream;

  // si estamos pidiendo la ruta principal, devolvemos el contenido del index.html
  if (url === "/") {
    stream = fs.createReadStream("index.html");
  } else if (url.match(".css$")) {
    // para los archivos CSS
    contentType = CSS_CONTENT_TYPE;
    stream = fs.createReadStream(`${PUBLIC_FOLDER}${url}`);
  } else if (url.match(".js$")) {
    // para los archivos JavaScript
    contentType = JS_CONTENT_TYPE;
    stream = fs.createReadStream(`${PUBLIC_FOLDER}${url}`);
  } else {
    // si llegamos aquí, es un 404
    statusCode = 404;
  }

  // escribimos las cabeceras de la respuesta dependiendo de la request
  res.writeHead(statusCode, { "Content-Type": contentType });
  // si tenemos un stream, lo enviamos a la respuesta
  if (stream) stream.pipe(res);
  // si no, devolvemos un string diciendo que no hemos encontrado nada
  else return res.end("Not found");
};

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log(`'app funcionando en el puerto 8000 http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

---

La otra opción es utilizar express, lo cual simplifica mucho el trabajo, para esto tu código debería quedar algo así:

```
//Lo utilizaremos para la ruta del index y el static del public
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");

//Nuestro server será manejado ahora por express
const app = express();
const host = "localhost";
const port = 8000;

//Definimos la carpeta public como estática, ahora podemos poner en ella lo necesario, css, js, imagenes, etc.
app.use(express.static("public"));

//Definimos ruta utilizando express
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
//Enviamos el index.html al browser.
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});

//Escuchamos server
app.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log(`'app funcionando en el puerto 8000 http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

Aquí también está escrito de forma tal que en el mismo lugar que el "index.html" tengamos una carpeta "public" con el archivo .css adentro.

Y también debemos invocar el archivo css desde el index.html como indico al principio de la respuesta.

Espero te sea de ayuda, cualquier cosa estoy a las ordenes.