# Es posible renderizar css,js(archivos estáticos) con puro nodejs SIN utilizar EXPRESS

Tags: nodejs

Esto es lo que llevo pero solo me renderiza el html
y en el html tengo bien vinculado el css y el js,
se que se puede hacer facil con express pero me lo estan pidiendo sin este

```
const http = require('http');
const host = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const requestListener = function(req,res){
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html')
    .then(contents => {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html');
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(contents)
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.writeHead(500);
        red.end(err)
    });
}

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);

server.listen(port,host,()=>{
    console.log('server on port',3000)
})
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como servir correctamente archivos estáticos en node.js?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310831/como-servir-correctamente-archivos-est%c3%a1ticos-en-node-js)

Comment: @MauricioContreras la pregunta que citas usa `express` y el usuario especifica en su pregunta que no quiere usarlo. No es un duplicado, al menos no de esa pregunta.

Comment: No obstante @EdwinAlbarracin, la respuesta de Mauricio Contreras en esa pregunta que te comenta da una solución también sin express. Puedes checarla también.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez la pregunta no cita Express salvo en el código, donde el OP tenía un enredo usando tanto el módulo `http` como `express` al mismo tiempo. El título de la pregunta es claro: *¿Como servir correctamente archivos estáticos en node.js?*, tampoco menciona Express. Es por ello que la marqué como duplicada. En todo caso, como no quedaba definida en esa pregunta si usaba Express o NodeJS (usaba ambos de forma caótica), decidí responder para ambos casos en ese momento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí es posible aunque no es muy recomendado. Hay muchos aspectos de seguridad, integridad y muchas funciones que librerías como `express` manejan por ti, pero de cualquier forma pides es posible hacerlo de forma nativa con `node`.

Crea en una carpeta para el servidor que estará conformado por una carpeta `public` con los archivos que vas a servir y un archivo `app.js` correspondiente a tu servidor. Debería verse algo así:

```
├── app.js
└── public
    ├── css
    │   └── style.css
    ├── index.html
    └── test.json
```

Coloca el siguiente código en tu archivo `app.js`:

```
const http = require('http')
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const port = 3000;
const mimeTypes = {
    '.html': 'text/html',
    '.js': 'text/javascript',
    '.css': 'text/css',
    '.json': 'application/json',
    '.png': 'image/png',
    '.jpg': 'image/jpg',
    '.gif': 'image/gif',
    '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
    '.wav': 'audio/wav',
    '.mp4': 'video/mp4',
    '.woff': 'application/font-woff',
    '.ttf': 'application/font-ttf',
    '.eot': 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject',
    '.otf': 'application/font-otf',
    '.wasm': 'application/wasm',
};


function send404(response) {
    response.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    response.write('Error 404: Resource not found.');
    response.end();
}


const requestListener = (req, res) => {
    const { url } = req;
    const filePath = `./public/${url}`;
    const extname = String(path.extname(filePath)).toLowerCase();
    const contentType = mimeTypes[extname] || 'text/plain';

    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content) => {
        if (err) {
            send404(res)
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
            res.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    })
}

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server on port ' + port)
})
```

Como puedes apreciar, todos los archivos que coloques en `public` que se encuentren entre los `mimeTypes` descritos en el código anterior podrán ser servidos.

El código es muy simple. El `requestHandler` extrae la `url` del recurso solicitado y lo convierte en una ruta a tu carpeta `public`. Posteriormente se intenta leer el recurso con `fs`. Si el recurso se lee con éxito, se envía con el `mimeType` correspondiente al archivo. Si hay algún error, se llama a la función `send404`.

Realicé pruebas con el `json` y llamando al `html` con una etiqueta link de la siguiente forma y los estilos se cargan con éxito:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo!