# Obtener __dirname estando en localhost con nodejs

Tags: nodejs, express, rutas, backend, ejs

Soy recién llegado a node.js y tengo problemas para referenciar o "llamar" con exito un fichero js que tengo en la carpeta "public" en una de mis vistas con el motor de plantillas EJS.

Mi estructura de carpetas actual es la siguiente:

[image: Mi estructura de carpetas actual]

En mi archivo .ejs, justo antes del cierre de body tengo lo siguiente. Donde url es en realidad __dirname, ya que se la he pasado como parametro desde el res.render()

```
<script src="<%= url + "/js/alert.js" %>"></script>
```

Este alert.js es de prueba y simplemente debería ejecutar una alert (pero no lo hace):

```
alert("POR FIN FUNCIONA!");
```

Estoy trabajando en local, por lo que en el navegador mi ruta es:
"http://localhost:5000/"

Pero si hago un console.log(__dirname) el resultado es la ruta dentro de mi maquina, es decir, "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Programación web\Control-finanzas" y no "http://localhost:5000/".

Si trato de acceder al recurso en cuestión accediendo a "http://localhost:5000/js/alert.js" sí que puedo visualizarlo en el navegador, pero no puedo colocar esa ruta de manera estática en el .ejs ya que al subirlo a un servidor real no funcionará. Necesito un modo de imprimir de manera dinàmica "http://localhost:5000" si estoy en local o la "url definitiva" cuando esté el proyecto ya subido a un servidor.

Os dejo también mi app.js por si puede ser de ayuda. Veréis que en los console.log() he hecho algunas pruebas con cosillas que he encontrado por internet pero ninguno funciona. He comentado lo que me retorna cada uno de esos console.log().

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
console.log(__dirname); //C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Programación web\Control-finanzas


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');  //Motor de plantillas EJS
app.set('views', __dirname+'/views');   //Directorio que contiene las vistas

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("# El servidor ya esta a la espera de peticiones del cliene por el puerto", port);
});
console.log(server.address().address);     //"::"
console.log(server.address().port);        //5000

const os = require("os");
console.log(os.networkInterfaces().Ethernet[1].address);    //192.xxx.x.xx (he censurado con x por precaución)
console.log(os.hostname());                                //PC_de_Pepito (nombre de mi máquina. Adulterado, sí)

app
   .get("/", (req, res) => {
        console.log(res.header.host);  //undefined
        res.render("dashboard", {titulo: "Dashboard", url: __dirname});
    })
    /* aquí van otros .get() irrelevantes que omitiré */
    .use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))
    .use((req, res, next) => {
        console.log("### Use 404");
        res.status(404).sendFile(__dirname+"/public/404.html"); //Curiosamente aquí si que me muestra la pagina adecuada e incluyo "/public/" en la ruta, de otro modo no funciona
    })
```

Mil gracias por vuestro tiempo! (:

Comment: `__dirname` apunta al directorio desde donde se ejecuta el script de entrada al proceso. Para trabajar con plantillas y servir archivos estáticos puedes leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310831/como-servir-correctamente-archivos-est%c3%a1ticos-en-node-js/311082#311082). Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, toda ruta que uses en tu plantilla será relativa al `host` que sirva tus archivos, la ruta nunca la necesitarás de forma absoluta con `__dirname` en tu plantilla. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas que tiene que tener en cuenta, una de ellas es que debe resolver el __direname para que no tenga problemas. Otra cosa es que debe instanciar las configuraciones antes de solicitar cualquier ruta y no encadenar los métodos ya que tendría resultados diferentes/inesperados. Le dejo el código de como yo lo haría:

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = 5000;


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("### Use 404");
  res.status(404).sendFile("./404.html");
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(res.header.host);  // host no existe por defecto al recibir una petición GET desde el navegador, por eso undefined
  res.render("dashboard", { titulo: "Dashboard" });
})

// Acá irían los demás controladores que omitió, pero debe mantener la misma estructura que el anterior

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("# El servidor ya esta a la espera de peticiones del cliene por el puerto", port);
});

/*
Solo en caso de que se quiera usar en algún otro módulo, si no es el caso, se puede prescindir de la constante server
y se usa como:

app.listen(port, () => { 
  ...
})

y listo
*/


module.exports = {
  server
} 

/*
Solo en caso de que se quiera usar en algún otro módulo, si no es el caso, se puede prescindir de exportar la constante server
*/
```

y en la plantilla simplemente basta con:

```
<script src="./js/alert.js"></script>
```

Ahora, si es completamentes imprescindible enviar una ruta (o cualquier otra variable) es mejor enviarla directamente desde el controlador, es la responsabilidad de este enviar toda la data y no de la vista calcular nada.

*controlador:*

```
...
res.render("dashboard", { titulo: "Dashboard", url:'./js/alert.js' });
```

*Vista (o plantilla):*

```
<script src=<%= url %></script>
```