# Problema al enlazar bootstrap.min.css con mi html

Tags: html, css, nodejs, bootstrap, npm

Tengo una carpeta raiz que contiene otras carpetas con los proyectos Bootstrap que voy a hacer, ademas de esos proyectos tengo otra carpeta llamada "z_BSfiles" donde instale Bootstrap usando el instalador de paquetes de Nodejs, y queria que todos los proyectos usaran los archivos que se instalaron ahi, pero al importar con `<link>` en el html de uno de los proyectos no me deja acceder a los estilos, me tira el error :

```
`"Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/z_BSfiles/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."`
```

este es el head:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../z_BSfiles/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

una foto de la carpeta raiz solo por las dudas:

[image]

intente poniendo la ruta absoluta, pero igual me tira un error de que no se pudo acceder al recurso. Estoy seguro de que esta bien escrita porque tengo una extension de autocompletado de rutas que muestra las carpetas y archivos por donde voy pasando al escribir dicha ruta. No entiendo que esta pasando. Estoy usando VSCode y Live Server.

Comment: Esa no es la forma correcta de [servir archivos estáticos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310831/como-servir-correctamente-archivos-est%c3%a1ticos-en-node-js) en NodeJS. Nunca expongas directamente la ruta a la carpeta `node_modules`. De hecho, nunca expongas directamente una aplicación de [tag:nodejs] a Internet, debes usar un servidor proxy inverso. Saludos

Comment: lo tendre en cuenta gracias

Comment: usare los links CDN de bootstrap y listo, no se usar express.js

Comment: Revisa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type