# ¿Cómo comunico dos ficheros en NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, express

en ésta parte del código necesito agregar otro fichero además de index.html y que se comuniquen entre sí con nodeJS:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});
```

Comment: No sé mucho de nodejs, pero la función `get` describe lo que se hará cuando el usuario acceda a tal parte del sitio. La **/** simboliza el directorio raíz. Si tu sitio fuera el de Google, correspondería con la URL https://www.google.com .

Comment: A que te refieres con: _agregar otro fichero y que se comuniquen entre si con nodeJs_ ? Solo con esa pregunta creo que tienes los conceptos muy erróneos de que es nodejs, para que sirve, que es HTML y como se comunican entre ellos. Puedes aclarar mejor tu pregunta?

Comment: Tu app devuelve un archivo html cuando le llega un request GET al endpoint `/`, ahora bien, a qué te refieres con "agregar otro fichero", quieres enviar otro archivo más además del que ya envías?

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Cómo servir correctamente archivos estáticos en NodeJS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310831/como-servir-correctamente-archivos-est%c3%a1ticos-en-node-js)

Comment: ya lo he solucionado por mi cuenta

Comment: Considera agregar tu solución como una respuesta, para así poder ayudar a toda la comunidad cuando alguien tenga un problema similar. Saludos