# Como mostrar las imágenes alojadas en mi pc con NODEJS y REACT

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de mostrar las imágenes que tengo en mi pc, en una carpeta, en concreto con nodejs y react, ya que tengo una carpeta en src, en mi proyecto nodejs, con mis imagenes y quisiera que cuando se acceda a una ruta en concreto por medio de react, esas imagenes se enviaran hacia la persona que esta accediendo y se mostraran las imagenes, ya lo intente bastante, pero no he conseguido que cuando se acceda a la ruta que quiero, se muestren las imagenes y siempre me termina dando un error:
NODE:

```
router.get("/Manga/:manga/:capitulo", async (req, res) => {
  const { manga, capitulo } = req.params;
  const images = await ReadDirectory(
    join(resolve(__dirname, ".."), "Manga", manga, capitulo)
  );

  res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "image/jpeg" }); // Establece el tipo de contenido para las imágenes

  const imagePaths = images.map((img) => {
    const cap = join(manga, capitulo, img);
    return `/${cap}`;
  });

  res.json(imagePaths);
});
```

La funcion con la que recibo las imagenes:

```
export const getImages = async (Manga, Chapter) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:4000/Manga/${Manga}/${Chapter}`
  );
  const images = await response.json();
  return images;
};
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como servir correctamente archivos estáticos en node.js?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310831/como-servir-correctamente-archivos-est%c3%a1ticos-en-node-js)