# Se bloqueó la carga de un módulo de “url” debido a un tipo MIME no permitido (“text/html”)

Tags: nodejs, express, ecmascript-6

Estoy aprendiendo módulos de EcmaScript6, todo bien a excepcion de un error, al tratar de ejecutarse mi modulo principal, obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Se bloqueó la carga de un módulo de “http://localhost:3000/DomEvents” debido a un tipo MIME no permitido (“text/html”).
```

¿Como puedo solucionarlo? como servidor estoy usando uno montado con el framework express en nodeJS

No tengo ninguna  otra dependencia ademas de express (porque monte el servidor con el único objetivo de practicar el uso de módulos de EcmaScript6.

Pensé inicializar la cabecera content-type para indicar el tipo "text/javascript" como solución pero
no se como, ya que estoy sirviendo el archivo con un controlador ya hecho que tiene express, generado a partir de `express.static("ruta")` . entonces no puedo controlar la respuesta por esa razón que plantee

Archivo: server.js

```
const express = require("express")
const expressApp = express()

expressApp.use(express.static('./'))

expressApp.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("I'm listening")
})
```

Modulo principal del lado del cliente:

```
import {Message,Alert} from "./DomEvents";

document.querySelector("h1").textContent = "Toad"
```

Comment: ¿Estás intentando correr el código con un HTML?

Comment: No...el código de lado del servidor esta en un archivo .js, mmm ya voy a especificar bien los ficheros a los que pertenece cada código.

Comment: Bueno, a eso me refería. Que el código lo corrías con una página web. Recuerda que [express.js](https://expressjs.com/es/) es un *framework* para desarrollo backend. Para ejecutar el fichero `app.js`, abre una consola en el mismo directorio donde se encuentra el fichero y ejecuta el comando `node ./app.js`.

Comment: Ese no es el problema, el problema es al momento en el que mi servidor sirve archivos estaticos, en el javascript del lado del cliente quiero usar módulos y obtengo el error que coloque en la pregunta cuando se va a descargar

Answer (score 1):

Bien, para importar correctamente un modulo siempre debo poner la extensión del archivo a diferencia de cuando se usa `require` en node

La forma correcta es así, mi problema era ese el no haber puesto la extensión :

```
import {Message,Alert} from "./DomEvents.js";
```

Por eso me daba ese error ya que el navegador no lo consideraba un script si no contenido de texto.

Comment: Eso no es correcto, y tu solución funciona debido a que al colocar la extensión la petición del navegador es explícita. Los módulos en JS están pensados para realizar la importación sin usar la extensión. Lo que debes hacer es configurar las cabeceras apropiadas para las solicitudes de archivos estáticos en Express. En [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310405/deploy-en-heroku-pero-no-cargan-los-estilos-de-mi-aplicación/310731#310731) respuesta doy una explicación de cómo establecer las cabeceras en esos casos. Saludos