# Establecer una cabecera para cargar Js y CSS en Node - Express

Tags: css, nodejs, express, mime

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con ayuda de NodeJS, usando el servidor de Express. Al querer establecer las cabeceras para que el CSS y los scripts JS se ejecuten me arroja los siguientes errores:

> GEThttp://localhost:8080/styles/styles.css
> GEThttp://localhost:8080/scripts/grabaAudio.js
> Ha fallado la carga del  con origen "http://localhost:8080/scripts/grabaAudio.js". localhost:8080:24:1
> GEThttp://localhost:8080/styles/Record (online-voice-recorder.com).mp3
> [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 4ms]
> El recurso de “http://localhost:8080/styles/styles.css” fue bloqueado debido a una discordancia del tipo MIME (“text/html”) (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff). localhost:8080
> El recurso de “http://localhost:8080/scripts/grabaAudio.js” fue bloqueado debido a una discordancia del tipo MIME (“text/html”) (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff). localhost:8080
> La carga HTTP ha fallado con el estado 404. Ha fallado la carga del recurso de medios http://localhost:8080/styles/Record%20(online-voice-recorder.com).mp3. localhost:8080
> GEThttp://localhost:8080/imgs/cloud.png
> [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]

Éste es el código de mi index.js :

```js
    //Importamos los módulos necesarios
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const mime = require('mime');
    //Creamos una instancia de express
    const app = express('');
    //The local server is confingurated in the port 8080
    const port = 8080;


    // escribimos la función que creará nuestra cabecera
    const setHeadersOnStatic = (res, path, stat) => {
        const type = mime.getType(path);
        res.set('content-type', type);
      }

    // creamos el objeto con las opciones
    const staticOptions = {
        setHeaders: setHeadersOnStatic
      }
      
    // usamos las opciones
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), staticOptions) );

    //telling the express module that the public dir has all of our site assets
    //app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    /*
    //app.use(express.static('proyecto/styles/styles.css'));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/proyecto'));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/styles'));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/scripts'));*/

    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
    });

    app.listen(port, () => {
        //If the server is running correctly
        console.log('Server started on port :',port);
    });
```

Como pueden notar, hago uso de una función la cual determina el tipo de cabecera para después asignarla.

Ya estuve investigando, probando y analizando lo de estos post y nada :(

1. [Deploy en heroku pero no cargan los estilos de mi aplicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310405/deploy-en-heroku-pero-no-cargan-los-estilos-de-mi-aplicaci%C3%B3n/310731#310731)
2. [¿Cómo servir correctamente archivos estáticos en node.js?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310831/como-servir-correctamente-archivos-est%C3%A1ticos-en-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente pude resolverlo, pongo aquí la info por si a alguien le llega a servir.

```js
//Creamos una variable para guardar la carpeta en donde están alojados los archivos estáticos(views)
const src = path.join(__dirname, "views");

//Definimos los toda la carpeta como archivos estáticos
app.use(express.static(src));

//Finalmente al llamar index, indicamos que está dentro de la variable src
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(src + 'index.html');
});
```

Y listo, así de sencillo.
Existen diferentes formas de tratar con archivos estáticos, en mi caso esta fue la que me funcionó.